# Why value_counts in one column of the dataset adds everything except one specific category (DDoS)?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset using three csv, and I need to know the unique values and their quantity in one specific column (Label), to plot later. It works perfectly until DDoS. I already check the raw data and everything is fine. How can I solve this issue?

`dataset['Label'].value_counts()`

Probe         98129

DDoS          73529

Normal        68424

DoS           53616

DDoS          48413

BFA            1405

Web-Attack      192

BOTNET          164

U2R              17

Name: Label, dtype: int64

Answer (score 1):

It seems that they are different in way invisble to you, consider following snippet

```
import pandas as pd
labels = pd.Series(['DDoS','DDoS','DDoS','DDoS '])
print(labels.value_counts())
```

output

```
DDoS     3
DDoS     1
dtype: int64
```

It does look similar to your case, however when you do

```
print(labels.value_counts().index)
```

output

```
Index(['DDoS', 'DDoS '], dtype='object')
```

Situation is explained - there is `DDoS` and `DDoS`  (i.e. `DDoS` followed by space) which are different strings. If this is case you might use `.str.strip` as follows

```
dataset['Label'].str.strip().value_counts()
```

Note that it will remove any leading/trailing whitespaces (like `\t`), not only spaces.

Comment: To remove whitespace, you can use `strip()`

`dataset['Label'].str.strip().value_counts()`

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the two `DDoS` values are not the same (a whitespace character somewhere?)

You can try to

```
dataset['Label'].str.strip().value_counts()
```